# Incomplete answers returned by OpenAI API

Tags: javascript, node.js, openai-api

I'm using the OpenAI API to get answers to my questions. However, I've noticed that sometimes the API returns an incomplete answer that looks like it's cut off in the middle of a word. On the other hand, if I ask the same question using the ChaGPT model, I get a complete answer.

I've checked that my question is properly formatted and meets the API's requirements. I'm sure that my internet connection is stable, and that
I'm using the correct parameters for the request.

```
fetch(url, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    model: "text-davinci-003",
    prompt: "how to make 54 cheese pizza?",
  }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
```

result:

```
{
  id: '***',
  object: 'text_completion',
  created: 1686141689,
  model: 'text-davinci-003',
  choices: [
    {
      text: '\n\n1. Preheat oven to 425 degrees Fahrenheit.\n\n2.',
      index: 0,
      logprobs: null,
      finish_reason: 'length'
    }
  ],
  usage: { prompt_tokens: 7, completion_tokens: 16, total_tokens: 23 }
```

Can anyone help me understand why the OpenAI API is returning an incomplete answer, and what I can do to fix it?

Comment: If ChatGPT gives you a very long answer it will cut off after a while and ask you if it should continue generating the answer or not. The same thing happens with the OpenAI API. I guess the API provides a way to disable this automatic cutoff.

Comment: @AztecCodes its not very long ansver and chatGPT didnt ask me "should continue generating the answer or not"

Comment: @Minesweeper in your answer you can see "finish_reason: 'length'" message. have you tried looking for this message in the documentation?

Comment: @Minesweeper True as you can see the finish reason is length. So I am probably right.

Comment: @AztecCode how can i fix it?